# Xcode - Open Terminal window from Mac app and run script file in it

Tags: xcode, terminal, applescript, sandbox, mac-app-store

In our Mac app we need to open a new Terminal window and run our generated AppleScript file inside it. The AppleScript file can be generated in application's storage directory (where a sandbox app can read/write).

Our requirement is very specific - we need to open a Terminal window and runs the AppleScript file there followed by ExpectScript file run to make user SSH to some server, and user may able to input in that Terminal window (if requires).

We have our AppleScript and ExpectScript files created but we need to find a way to open the Terminal window and runs the AppleScript in it.

We tried by `NSTask`. We ran the AppleScript file which has the path to ExpectScript file, however the AppleScript file did ran it refused to run the ExpectScript file following this error type:
`execution error LSOpenURLsWithRole() -10820`

We tried to use `NSUserAppleScriptTask` command. This worked good but the script files requires to be in application script directory, where a sandbox app can't write. So this not worked for us either.

Is there any way we can do the above in a sandbox Mac app - opening Terminal window and run script file in it?

Comment: The way i did it, but the app is not sent for approval yet, is to instruct the user to place the script in the scripts directory. I use the save panel for this. You can then communicate from the cocoa app with the scripts and do things the sandboxed app cant. The user will know about this, not sure apple how feels it but if they gave access to that scripts folder i hope is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately in our case the scripts generates at run-time and placed to application storage directory (since we can't save to application script directory in sandbox app). I tried many hacky way but doing two things to at same time - I couldn't found a way - opening terminal and run commands in it. Apple is very restrictive to run Terminal window from a sandbox app and run arbitrary command in it.

Comment: I can confirm now after rejection of another app that my idea will not work because it requires root access (appstore guidelines - Performance - 2.4.5). I guess the only way is to instruct the user on your website to install additional scripts and stuff, i saw this in one app.